# How to find device whose major id is "fd"

Tags: linux, files, devices

In /proc/locks I have:

```
21: POSIX  ADVISORY  READ  6813 fd:02:32374949 1073741826 1073742335
```

On the other hand `/dev` does not have any device with major id of **`fd`**.
Does anyone know what to do in this case? I am on fedora 22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have any?  `fd` is decimal 253 which is the `virtblk` device driver (eg vda2).

```
% ls -l /dev/vda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 2 Aug 24 07:49 /dev/vda2
```

Alternatively,if you want to find the actual file it's pointing to, rather than the device, we could cheat and look at `/proc/6813/fd` to see what files that process has open and compare them to the inode numbers.

eg I see in my `/proc/locks` the entry:

```
21: FLOCK  ADVISORY  WRITE 1324 fd:03:390139 0 EOF
```

So

```
find -L /proc/1324/fd -maxdepth 1 -inum 390139 -exec readlink {} \;
```

(the -L will follow the `/proc/.../fd` symlinks to the real file, so we can check the inode number of the target; the `maxdepth` will mean that any symlinks to directories won't be followed).

In this case I get

```
# find -L /proc/1324/fd -maxdepth 1 -inum 390139 -exec readlink {} \;
/var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I did not realize they use hex numbers...